# Kohana not resubmit when displaying message

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, kohana, submit

in kohana controllers that involve form manipulations, i use to declare a vire message like:

```
            $this->view->message = __('mESSAGE HERE');
```

for the user to know that the form has been successfully submited.

in the form i have:

```
<? if(isset($message)):?>
<p class="message"><?= $message; ?></p>
```

```
    <form id=.........
```

so after some submit the form, if it was a succes, it is displayed a message. my problem is:

if this person refreshes the page, the form is resubmited :(( can this be avoided somehow? (eventually without using redirect, but just javascript/jquery)?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hidden field with a random string (only when POST is empty!). The same string (token) saves in session. So, after succesfully submit you need to clear session key. Also, this method helps to avoid [cross-site request forgeries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention)

Anyway, redirect is the best way to prevent the user from the confusing messages about re-sending the request data